# Deploying Azure Static Web App results in manifest error

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-devops, azure-static-web-app

I'm trying to deploy my React app to a Static Web App in Azure using an Azure DevOps build pipeline. The deployment seems to be going fine and succeeds. Unfortunately, when I open the url of the SWA I see te following error:

```
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

This is the manifest:

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Now I double checked my pipeline, and I think it's correct:

```
trigger:
  - main

variables:
  vmImageName: "ubuntu-latest"
  deployment_token: xxxxx

stages:
  - stage: Deploy_to_dev
    displayName: Deploy to dev
    jobs:
      - job: Deploy_to_dev
        displayName: Deploy to dev
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            submodules: true
          - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
            inputs:
              app_location: "/" # App source code path relative to cwd
              azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token)
              app_build_command: "npm run build:dev"
              output_location: "/build"
              config_file_location: "/"
              skip_api_build: true
              deployment_environment: "development"
```

Does anyone know how I should tackle this?

Comment: If you're getting a manifest error, it would probably help if you posted the manifest along with your question.

Answer (score 0):

**I have tried to repro the same by creating a simple react app in VS code.**

**Step 1:** Create a simple react app using the below command.

```
npx create-react-app react-test-swa --use-npm
```

Below is the react app folder structure created and find **manifest.json** file under the public folder.
[image]

**Note: I have not modified anything in manifest.json file at this time.**

manifest.json:

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

**Step 3:** Push the code to Azure Repos.
[image]

**Step 4:** Create Azure Static Webapp.
While creating Azure static webapp, I chose the deployment model as **Other**
[image]

**Step 5:** Create pipeline as below.
[image]

```
steps:
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      app_location: '/'
      app_build_command: 'npm run build'
      output_location: 'build'
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: '$(deployment_token)'
      deployment_environment: 'Development'
```

Now, when I run the pipeline, it shows the success result and able to access the web app.

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you are still facing issues after following all these steps, I would ask you to share your source code to debug further.

Comment: Saying "I couldn't reproduce the problem" *is not an answer*

Comment: @Sourav It's *not* an answer. It's a series of tutorial steps. It's not addressing the actual issue that the person who asked the question is facing.